# Incorrect Total Calculation in nested measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following measure that is doing wrong calculation

```
SummerizeConsumption = 
VAR _Table = SUMMARIZE('Chips Consuption Query','Chips Consuption Query'[Component.Component Level 01.Key])
RETURN SUMX(_Table,[Consumption])
```

here measure formula for [Consumption]

```
[Consumption]=
var Val1 = CALCULATE(SUMX(
    VALUES('Parent Consumption Query'[Component.Component Level 01.Key]), IF('Parent Consumption Query'[Component.Component Level 01.Key] IN { "P1","P2","P3","P4","P5" }, 'Parent Consumption Query'[Parent Issue Stock Qty.]) ))
    
   var val2 = CALCULATE(SUMX(
    VALUES('Parent Production Query'[Material.Material Level 01.Key]), IF('Parent Production Query'[Material.Material Level 01.Key] IN { "P1","P2","P3","P4","P5" }, 'Parent Production Query'[Parent Production Qty.]) ))

RETURN DIVIDE(Val1,val2)

 
'Parent Consumption Query'[Parent Issue Stock Qty.]= SUM('Parent Consumption Query'[Issue Total Stock])  
'Parent Production Query'[Parent Production Qty.] =SUM('Parent Production Query'[Activity quantity])
```

My issue is that SummerizeConsumption is not calculating total correctly as shown below

[image]

Comment: What is your model ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the context. I see that the SummerizeConsumption measure aggregates data from a summarized table but then applies the [Consumption] measure across it.
If [Consumption] relies on context that is not preserved in _Table, this could lead to incorrect results.

The SUMX in SummerizeConsumption iterates over _Table, but the [Consumption] measure involves context transition through CALCULATE which might not behave as expected due to the lack of context from the original tables.

```
VAR _Table = SUMMARIZE(
    'Chips Consuption Query',
    'Chips Consuption Query'[Component.Component Level 01.Key],
    "Consumption", [Consumption] 
)
RETURN SUMX(_Table, [Consumption])
```